# Asymptotic behavour of a function.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, asymptotics

Let $c>0$ and $f:[0, \infty)\to\mathbb R^+$ a non negative function such that

$$f(t)\leq -c\int_0^tf(s)ds+\int_0^te^{-s}\sqrt{f(s)}ds.$$

Is it possible to prove that $\lim_{t\to +\infty} f(t)=0$?

Without the second term in the sum I would be able to conclude that $f(t)\leq f(0) e^{-ct}$. How can I conclude with this extra term?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I think it might not be possible to show that the limit is zero. To see why, say you've constructed an initial portion of $f$ on $[0, t_0]$ such that $-c \int_{0}^{t_0} f(s) \, ds + \int_{0}^{t_0} e^{-s} \sqrt{f(s)} \, ds > 0$. You could then *mostly* let $f$ get small as $t \to \infty$, but still add narrow bumps of height $1$ arbitrarily far out without violating the inequality. That is, the bumps would get narrower and narrower the farther you went out.

Comment: am I missing something? don't we have $f(t)\le -c\int_0^tf(s)ds+\int_0^te^{-s}\sqrt{f(s)}ds<0$ because the RHS is just $<0$?